# Can't run a pig script on apache Zeppelin

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, apache-zeppelin

```
> org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 4010:
> Cannot find hadoop configurations in classpath (neither
> hadoop-site.xml nor core-site.xml was found in the classpath). If you
> plan to use local mode, please put -x local option in command line at
> org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.getExecConf(HExecutionEngine.java:157)
> at
> org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.init(HExecutionEngine.java:194)
> at
> org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.init(HExecutionEngine.java:111)
> at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.connect(PigContext.java:310) at
> org.apache.pig.PigServer.<init>(PigServer.java:232) at
> org.apache.pig.PigServer.<init>(PigServer.java:220) at
> org.apache.pig.PigServer.<init>(PigServer.java:193) at
> org.apache.pig.PigServer.<init>(PigServer.java:185) at
> org.apache.zeppelin.pig.PigInterpreter.open(PigInterpreter.java:61) at
> org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:69)
> at
> org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:617)
> at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188) at
> org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:140)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have tried run a pig script on apache Zeppelin but it gives me this error.I have checked all the configurations and settings but unable to resolve this.

Comment: What configurations did you check and where? What files are in your `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` environment variable? Can you please show your Pig configuration properties in the question? Can you run Pig shell outside Zeppelin?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66433489/running-pig-query-on-apache-zeppelin
please help me on this

Answer (score 1):

Please check the doc here. https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/interpreter/pig.html
Most likely you set execution mode as mapreduce, but didn't configure HADOOP_CONF_DIR

Comment: Thanks for your interest. The issue got fixed.